# Handling Previous Activities

Tags: android

I have a spinner that essentially starts multiple new activities based on onItemSelect();

However, what's happening on my app is if I start the same activity multiple times I have to hit the Android back button multiple times.  How do I start the same activity and kill the previous one so that I don't have multiple layouts sitting there open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `android:noHistory=true` for your `<activity>` in `Manifest.xml`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory)

Or, programatically:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) activity flag.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new activity you need to finish your old activity. So when you call your new intent:

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

That will end the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting the activity launchmode to "singletop" (this can be done in the Android Manifest).  Then instead of creating a new activity, it will call OnNewIntent() of the existing activity.